# Jupyter Notebook In Singularity Container

Tags: jupyter, singularity-container

How do i get a jupyter notebook up on my browser after I shell into my singularity container- I can't find much documentation on it? I am on a centos linux distribution that I have to ssh into.

Jupyter is already installed in the container. After you `singularity shell --writable ....sif`, how does one actually get a jupyter notebook running on the browser? The basic: `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=7800` gives back this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1628, in initialize
    self.init_configurables()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1319, in init_configurables
    connection_dir=self.runtime_dir,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 99, in _runtime_dir_default
    ensure_dir_exists(rd, mode=0o700)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/utils/__init__.py", line 13, in ensure_dir_exists
    os.makedirs(path, mode=mode)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/run/user/19241'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're given a link from the output after starting the notebook that you can just paste into your browser. See sample output below.

Are you sure the image was successfully built / transferred completely? I'm unable to replicate that error. If still getting that error, please update the question with your definition file / the command for how you generate the image.

```
$ singularity pull docker://jupyter/scipy-notebook
INFO:    Converting OCI blobs to SIF format
INFO:    Starting build...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 692c352adcf2 done
...
2020/08/31 09:23:15  info unpack layer: sha256:2be4f33acc3414896b4c608db82138711c62386174f91319cd1f317b54431fda
INFO:    Creating SIF file...
INFO:    Build complete: scipy-notebook_latest.sif

$ singularity shell scipy-notebook_latest.sif 
Singularity> jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=7800
[I 09:28:37.259 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/tsnowlan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 09:28:38.266 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 09:28:38.266 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
[I 09:28:38.269 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /data/playground/jupyter
[I 09:28:38.269 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.3 is running at:
[I 09:28:38.269 NotebookApp] http://localhost:7800/?token=xxxx
[I 09:28:38.269 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:7800/?token=xxxx
[I 09:28:38.269 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 09:28:38.273 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/tsnowlan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-114505-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:7800/?token=xxxx
     or http://127.0.0.1:7800/?token=xxxx
```

Comment: Hmmmm.  Thank you so much.  So I'm not completely clear.  First, I tried your commands.  I successfully pulled the above docker://jupyter/scipy-notebook  .  Then I tried shelling in.  I had a different response from the computer.  It just gave me a shell.  It doesn't give me a link with host for my browser.  Not sure why.  Also, I think my issue is slightly different:  When building the image, it already has the jupyter, torch etc.  installed.  My .ipynb files that I want to open are just on my cluster though.  How would I open them then?  Some sort of host port mapping may be needed?

Comment: If you check docker hub, there are different variants with pytorch, etc. Check to see if there's one with everything you need, and if not make a definition file with the closest as its base image and install your extra packages from that. You'll need to mount them in using either `-B path/on/host:/path/in/container` or just start the image from the directory with the notebooks, since that is auto-mounted. From the singularity shell you should be able to specify what you need, though I don't know the precise command offhand

Comment: Hmmmm.  Thank you so much.  First, I tried your commands.  I successfully pulled the above docker://jupyter/scipy-notebook  .  Then I tried shelling in.  I had a different response from the computer.  It just gave me a shell.  It doesn't give me a link with host for my browser.  Not sure why.  Also, I think my issue is slightly different: I have since tried "export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=" before "jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8000"  and it runs.  Unfortunately when I go onto my local and ssh -N -L 8000:localhost:8000 h@b.edu, I get channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused ?